# Сохранение положения RadioGroup

Tags: java, android, radiobutton

Есть RadioGroup, состоящий из двух элементов. Как сохранить их положение (т.е включена только одна кнопка из двух) и возможно ли дальнейшее "прочтение" их положения?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35601566/7566397

Answer (score 0):

[SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) вам в помощь. При изменении состояния сохраняете его в SharedPreferences, при открытии экрана по ключу достаете из SharedPreferences ид/константу и делаете активной радио кнопку в зависимости от константы.